# Hyperlinks to my site do not work without www. However www is not needed when typing the url

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have a website hosted by AWS amplify. The domain is managed by google domains.

If I type my domain without the www into a browser I have no issues. However, if I try to send someone a hyperlink without the www the user gets a server cannot be found error.

In my AWS amplify manager I have set both domains
[image]

Comment: You don't have any addresses listed for onthehighend.com.  You do for www.onthehighend.com.  It looks like you need to update your addresses in Google.  None of the browsers I have access to resolve the non-www site.

Comment: @stdunbar interesting. Maybe my browsers are caching data but for me typing the non-www url works fine. The only issue is hyperlinking. 

So the issue is with Google no AWS? I'm not exactly sure what to update.

Comment: You need an A record for the non-www address.  Currently [you have none](https://www.nslookup.io/domains/onthehighend.com/dns-records/).

Comment: @stdunbar Trying to do this now and the AWS docs say Google Domains are not compatible with A records.  #7 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-google-domains.html

Comment: But you DNS is hosted in Google so you'd update it there.  At the end of the day you've now spent a good amount of time on this - why not just leave everything `www` and not worry about the "naked" domain name?  What does it matter?